# Issues in scaling a winform opened as a dialog from excel addin

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, add-in, excel-addins

We have created a exceladdin which opens up many winform diaglogs from click of a custom ribbon buttons. On higher dpi machines the winform dialogs are distorted. The same dialogs open up fine as part of separate projects.
In short scaling is not working correctly when opening winform dialog from exceladdin.

**Steps tried so far,**

We have set AutoScalingMode to Dpi - didnt help.
We have looked at the AutoScalingDimensions & CurrentAutoScalingDimensions they remains for some reason.

Also we were able to work around the problem by calling the below lines in load method of each form. But we are not sure how it is working, hence don;t trust it to solve our problem in all the cases.

```
float width_ratio = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 1920);
float heigh_ratio = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 1080);
SizeF scale = new SizeF(width_ratio, heigh_ratio);
this.Scale(scale);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am also having trouble get a WinForms Excel Addin to scale correctly for different DPIs.